# Why are my images stretching out to max-size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to this, and I'm currently trying out modal images, using this html, css and javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Everything works fine, but the images that are smaller than the set max-size, get stretched out to that size. I'd rather have the smaller images staying small/in original size when opened up.
What in that code makes the images stretch? I can't see it.

Comment: set `max-width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

You are using 100% of your width hence whatever wrapper the image is sitting in will determine what the size of the image will be and the browser will automatically fit the image to the size of the wrapper

Answer (score -1):

I looked in the code, and some of the CSS was causing it. (Check lines 32 and 87 in the CSS below.)

I modified some of the code, check it out below. You can modify the `max-width` in the HTML of the image to your image size. (Note: The demo works better on the full page.)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  /*(Removed from original) width: 80%; */
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    /*(Removed from original) width: 100%; */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%; max-width:300px;">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No idea why you extensivly used JS to solve an issue that can be solved with a single CSS line. Also your JS code is really bad practise for mdoern web development. You shouldnt use `getElementsByClassName` anymore. Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` instead. Also you should not use `.style` function. Use `.classList` instead and apply changes through CSS to not cause specificty weight issues. Also inline style are hard to debug/troubleshot.

Comment: @tacoshy I took the JS from the website given. I am not a code reviewer, I just try to help answer questions.

Comment: @Leo Jupp that solved it, thank you!!